# Create Kivy widgets without using kv language?

Tags: python, widget, kivy

How to create Kivy widgets without using kv language and .kv files? I am new to kivy. I usually use Tkinter, but i found out that Kivy is good for creating Android apps, so I am learning how to use it. 
I know that Kivy widgets are made using .kv files, but i would like to create them like widgets in Tkinter.

```
# Creating widgets in tkinter:
# We'll assume tkinter is imported as tk    

label_1 = tk.Label(text='Hello World', bg='white')
label_1.pack()

# Creating widgets using Kivy in .py file

label_1 = Label(text='Hello World')  # eg. Not able to set color!
add_widget(label_1)

# Creating widgets using kv language

Label:
    text: "Hello World"
    color: 1,0,0,1
```

So, is there any way to make Kivy widgets completely in python? How could i set Kivy label color directly in python?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's an example of Kivy application without using kv lang:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Label(
            text='Hello, world',
            color=(1, 0, 0, 1)
        )


TestApp().run()
```

Basically `build` method of `kivy.app.App` instance has return a main widget object, in this case a `kivy.uix.Label` instance. To have more complex widget you should create a subclass of some layout class and then add widgets using `add_widget` method.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout


class TestWidget(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **args):
        super(TestWidget, self).__init__(**args)
        label = Label(
            text='Hello, world',
            color=(1, 0, 0, 1))
        self.add_widget(label)


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return TestWidget()


TestApp().run()
```

I'd like to encourage you to use kv lang anyway, since it makes the code simplier.

Answer (score 7):

It is completely possible to use python exclusively to write apps with kivy. I began using kivy about 6 month ago and quickly abandoned the kv files. I do not like "magical" code in the background making bindings. I know this is a preference thing and now that I know how the widgets and layouts work, it may be actually quicker to use the kv language. Things you need to do manually are keep handles between widgets throughout the widget tree and setup bindings using the kivy properties. There is a lot to learn but once you start getting it, the possibilities are endless. Most examples you find are very simple and I feel the documentation is very limited. I feel that if you are comfortable with python, you will actually learn more about how kivy works if you stay in python.

I'm marking Nykakin's answer as correct, but I just thought I'd share some details.